# What are new feautures of .Net framework 4.0 for C# and windows form Application Developers?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I am c# developer ,i Like adapt myself for new technologies, so i eager to read about .Net framework 4.0, what are the new feautures of .Net Framework 4.0 especially for c#.Net and Windows form Application Developers and also i need some articles for improve my skills in that?

Answer (score 10):

It is good to always update your self.Here is the link .

[Net Framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2.aspx)

[Net Framework 4.0](http://msdotnetsupport.blogspot.com/2009/06/27-new-features-of-net-framework-40.html)

Hope you will get your ans.

Answer (score 0):

This article on MSDN has a good write-up:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can get best answers from Google when you search ".Net Framework 4.0 Features"

[Click Here For Example](http://msdotnetsupport.blogspot.com/2009/06/27-new-features-of-net-framework-40.html)

Programming Languages

Common Language Runtime (CLR)

Base Class Libraries

Networking

Web

Client

Data

Communications

Workflow

Answer (score 0):

this article has a good summary of language-specific features:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9576/the-future-of-net-languages/2/